# Variable declaration in reactjs documentation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, reactjs-native

[react.js documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/) has following variable declarations:

```
var { Image, StyleSheet, Text, View } = React;
```

Could you tell what does it meant? Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

This is the [destructuring syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment), which is part of ES6.

Answer (score 3):

It's a feature of ES6 called destructuring. Essentially the same as writing:

```
var Image = React.Image;
var StyleSheet = React.StyleSheet;
var Text = React.Text;
var View = React.View;
```