# How object destructuring assignments work?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

How could this statement assigns?

```js
var { AppRegistry, View, StyleSheet, ListView } = React;
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Variable declaration in reactjs documentation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30290963/variable-declaration-in-reactjs-documentation)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) that is coming in ECMAScript 6.

```
var s = { a: 1, b: 2 }
var { a, b } = s;
```

will assign `1` to `a` and `2` to `b`.

Presumably, `React` is an object that has properties `AppRegistry`, `View` etc., and their values are being assigned to variables with the same name.

This syntax is, at the moment of this answer, not yet widely available.

Answer (score 1):

This is a new feature in ES6 as Amadan said. ES6 will be released soon and all modern browsers will support it eventually. A lot of projects use [Babel](https://babeljs.io/) together with webpack to compile code to ES5 synatax so that it can be used on any browsers.

React native have their own transforms which support part of ES6:

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/javascript-environment.html#content

So you don't need Babel and webpack if you are using their packager. In the future version facebook may use Babel as well.